# Can I create multiple snippet files for the same language in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, vscode-snippets

VS Code does allow you to scope entire files using the name, for example snippets created in "lua.json" will only be scoped to Lua files.

However is it possible to create multiple snippets files taking advantage of this scoping method? for example having "lua.json" , "luaAdvanced.json" , "luaRandom.json".

I know there is a scoping prefix you can do for each individual snippet, but with the amount of snippets I need to creating being able to scope them based on the file (without making the one file insanely long)

My current Lua snippets folder is over a thousand LOC and is as compressed as I can make it but it is still very long and hard to read. was looking for a way to break down this huge file into multiple ones without needing the very redundant

```json
"scope": ["lua"]
```

for each individual snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could just create multiple global snippet files and in each one, name them whatever you want, and then manually scope each snippet in them to the scope you want using the `scope` property, which takes a string, in which you can put multiple language IDs separated by commas ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-scope)).

I tried searching for related feature-requests. I found [Snippets as separate files #39989](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/39989) which seems spot on to what you're looking for. It got (unsatisfyingly?) closed as a duplicate of [Allow snippets to control the scope to which they are applicable
#22661](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22661), which is closed as a duplicate of [[snippets] Global snippet option
#13182](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13182) like a bad game of telephone. Though I think what was gained in generalization solves the problem you are looking to solve- just different than you might have imagined it to be solved in.